# Using Unix, when detecting a pattern, we need to detect its corresponding other pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep

When detecting the line containing the pattern ***night***, we need to detect its corresponding line containing the other pattern ***===*** which is just occurring at a higher line as shown below.

- File content:

> === test1.log
>   boo
>   bar
>   game
>   **=== file23.txt**
>   **night78**
>   far
>   **night**
>   text
>   **=== log3.c**
>   aaa
>   limit
>   **night3**

- Output:

> **=== file23.txt**
>   **night78**
>   **night**
>   **=== log3.c**
>   **night3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with awk with something like this:

```
 awk '/===/ {SEC=$0;PRINTED=0} /night/ {if(!PRINTED) print SEC; print $0; PRINTED=1;}' <file>
```

which will look for the `===` line and store that, and note that it has not yet printed that one.  Then if it finds the pattern `night` it will check if it has already printed the section header or not, print it if not, then print the current line and mark that it has already printed the section header.

Comment: when launching this command I'm getting below error. 
awk '/===/ {SEC=$0;PRINTED=0} /night/ {if(!PRINTED) print SEC; print $0; PRINTED=1;}' test.txt  
**awk: syntax error near line 1**  
**awk: bailing out near line 1**

Comment: I'm using GNU's `gawk` is it possible you're using a different one?  I have not tried this with, say, `mawk`

Comment: Thank you Eric! `gawk` worked properly!

Comment: I'm not able to pass to the command a variable $pattern. Can you please assist?

`gawk "/===/ {SEC=$0;PRINTED=0} /$pattern/ {if(!PRINTED) print SEC; print $0; PRINTED=1;}" describe.txt`

Comment: Changing to double quotes will let you pass `$pattern` but then you have to escape all the other places where `$` is used, like `$0` will have to become `\$0` and so forth

Answer (score 0):

Tried this with the sed

```
sed -n '/===/{
h
d
}
/night/{
G
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\
\1/p
}' inputFile
```

This is not exactly what you wanted, but quite similar.

```
=== file23.txt
night78
=== file23.txt
night
=== log3.c
night3
```

- `/==` hold current pattern in buffer
- `/night` match all lines containing token night
- `G` append current buffer to the current pattern space.
- `/s` swap the position of current patten string and current buffer string.